# Definition of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the right way to think of an ODE, in the sense of what it is. The intuitive notion and basic ODE resolution are not a problem for me. I am rather looking for a 'satisfactory' mathematical definition. I think it will be easier to express myself through an example.

Let's solve the ODE:

$y'x\sin(y)=0$

When searching a solution for the ODE we are looking for a function

$y:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto y(x)$

satisfying $y'(x)x\sin(y(x))=0$ $\forall x \in  \mathbb{R}$

We usually define:

$F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y,y') \mapsto F((x,y,y'))= y'x\sin(y)$

so that the ODE is rewritten as

$F((x,y,y'))=0$.

However, the dependence on variables makes me a bit 'reluctant' to this approach. The value of $y'$ is uniquely determined by the value of $y$, which is uniquely determined by the value of $x$ So we could define some functions $G$ and $H$ so that

$F((x,y,y'))=0 \Leftrightarrow G((x,y)) =0 \Leftrightarrow H(x)=0$

Shall we really consider the function $F$ and do $\mathbb{R}^3$-analysis (partial derivatives, etc) on it?

We can approach the problem from other point of view. We can define an operator $\mathscr{L}$ from the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in which the ODE makes sense, that we will refered as $C$, to itself.

$\mathscr{L}:C\to C$ given by $y \mapsto \mathscr{L}(y)=y'x\sin(y)$

So we are looking for some $y\in C$ satisfying $\mathscr{L}(y)=0$, where $0\in C$.

Are both approachs 'good' in a mathematical sense? In an utility sense? Are there better approachs? I would be very grateful if you could give your view on this topic or if you could bring some bibliography.

Comment: Regarding your "reluctance" on $F$, the proper way to write it is we have a function $F:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$, say defined as $F(a,b,c)=ca\sin(b)$. Then, what you're looking for is a function $y:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $F(x,y(x),y'(x))=0$. So, $F$ is a function $\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$, and what we require for a solution of an ODE is that a certain composite function, namely the composition of $x\mapsto (x,y(x),y'(x))$ with $F$ is the zero function $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: FOr your second approach, one small nitpick is you should write $\mathscr{L}(y)(x):= y'(x)x\sin(y(x))$  (i.e $\mathscr{L}(y)$ is a function so it has to be evaluated on a point $x$ to yield a number) if you want to be completely precise because otherwise in $\mathscr{L}(y)=y'x\sin(y)$, there's an extra $x$ which doesn't seem to have any purpose. So, yes, indeed we're looking for the null-set of $\mathscr{L}$; i.e the set of $y\in C$ such that $\mathscr{L}(y)=0$.

Comment: I think $x \in C$ as a function

Comment: Ok, if you're interpreting $x$ as the identity function $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, then that's fine. But then again, while $\sin(y')$ is completely obvious what is meant, the correct way to write it would be $\sin\circ y'$... but I guess now I'm just being too pedantic (though only because it seems that's what you're looking for based on your qn:).